# Pattern with simple arithmetic operators

Tags: algorithm, math, arithmetic-expressions

I’m trying to generate a pattern like this given the input

0,1,2,3,4,5....

I want

0,0,1,0,1,0.....

I can generate the pattern by doing X+1 MOD 2 but the input of 0 gives an output of 1 and I need 0

I have to implement this in the form of an equation no if statements but I can use ADD SUB MOD MUL DIV AND OR XOR

Comment: This is not related to programming.

Answer (score 1):

This gives the desired output:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    std::cout << (i && ((i + 1) % 2));
}
```

> 001010

But this uses [implicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) to `bool`. There other ways to get this output if conversions are allowed. Also, you can use [sign bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_bit) of `i-1`.